# SQL Server: update a field with divided and multiplied values from other field on the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb6

I want to update a field from my table with a value that comes from:
Transaction_Count field : 10 x 100
For example the Transaction_Count value: 3. Then the calculation should be: 3 : 10 x 100 = 30

But when I run the code, the result is 0 without leaving error message. As additional information I already created Support field of my Mining table with decimal(18,2) data type. How to get the correct result, can anybody help me?

Here's my code:

```
SQL = "Update Mining Set Support = Transaction_Count / 10 * 100"
Con.Execute (SQL)
```

Comment: As a note:  On Stack Overflow the database should go in the tags and not the title.  I fixed the tags.

Comment: You're right, I select the wrong tag.
Thanks for fixing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server, as you  have discovered, does integer division.  You can just rearrange the operands:

```
Update Mining
    Set Support = (100 * Transaction_Count) / 10;
```

Your expression was being evaluated as:

```
 (Transaction_Count / 10) * 100 =  (3 / 10) * 100
```

The `3 / 10` is `0` (and NOT 0.33333333) in SQL Server, because it does integer division.